# Obtaining SLD styles that works with a given OpenStreetMap shape files?

Tags: openstreetmap, style, sld

I have downloaded shapefiles from open street map. I want to apply different stylings to a single vector file(i.e different colours to highways, street roads, pathways etc). Is there any way to obtain SLD styles so that it look similar to open street map?

Comment: which gis software are you using?

Comment: mapserver is used